# SSIS how to find correct data types?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-data-types

Background: This is my day 1 of learning ETL. Had a little computer science training (not very systematically) before.

So I was learning this SSIS Tutorial on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), one of the steps is to remap column data types from a flat file.

[image]

I never ran into this kind of data types (I mean those [DT_WSTR] thing) before. My question is how do I find the correct data type in Flat File Connection Manager Editor for my destination column? A complete list of reference of datatypes would be perfect. Thanks everyone!

Comment: DT just stands for datatype.  Its giving you recommendations you are free to change it.  For instance, if the ETL tool finds you are using a column with 3 characters.  It will recommend nchar(3).  You are free to change this to say nvarchar(255) if you support unicode and wante more than 3 characters.  Again, ultimately you decide these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a rather complex beast. Despite SO best practice of not linking to external resources, I'm going to disregard it here

- http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2014/05/27/sql-server-ssis-and-biml-data-types/
- http://milambda.blogspot.com/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2010/12/22/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I need... Thank you!